# Answer clarification about the continuity of a two variable piecewise function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, elementary-set-theory, continuity

We have a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$ defined as:

$$\ f(x,y) = 0 \space,  xy \ne 0\\ f(0,y) = 1+y \space;  x = 0\\ f(x,0) = 1\space;  y = 0 $$

Let C denote the set of points where f is continuous and D denote the set of points
where f is discontinuous.

The question asks to determine whether C and D are open or closed in $\mathbb R2$

I figured out by the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity that the given function is continuous at every point in $\mathbb R2$ that satisfies $\ xy \ne 0$  and is discontinuous at every point on the $\ x$ and $\ y$ axes.

Thus, set D contains every point that lies on the coordinate axes except $(0,-1)$, while C contains the points in $\mathbb R2$ excluding those in D.

I believe that the set C should be open and the set D should be closed.

But the answer states otherwise - that C is not an open subset of $\mathbb R2$ and  D is not a closed subset of $\mathbb R2$. Can anyone verify and explain which statement is correct?

Comment: Your last line defining $f$ should probably be $f(x, 0) = 1$, not $f(0,0) = 1$.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni Edited, thank you. What do you think about the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$D$ is the two axes, except point $(0,-1)$ where $f(0,-1)=0$ and $f$ is continuous. So $D$ is neither open nor closed.

$C$ is $\{(x,y), xy \ne 0\} \cup \{(0,-1)\}$. So $C$ is neither open nor closed, too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Totally forgot about $(0,-1)$.